# NameError -- imported modules when script is broken down in multiple python files

Tags: python, python-2.7

It is hard to find a title for this question and hopefully this thread is not a duplicate.

I was writing that long script in Python 2.7 (using PyCharm 2016.2.2) for a project and decided to split it in different .py files which I could then import into a main file.

Unfortunately, it seems that when importing a module (e.g. numpy) earlier in the code does not mean that the .py files that are imported below will have knowledge of that.

I am new to python and I was wondering whether there is an easy workaround for that one.

To be more clear, here is an example structure of my code:

*Main.py* (the file that is used to run the script):

```
import basic
numpy.random.seed(7)
import load_data
```

*basic.py*:

```
import pandas
import numpy
            etc...
```

*load_data.py*:

```
raw_input = pandas.read_excel('April.xls', index_col = 'DateTime') 
            etc...
```

The second line of *Main.py* would cause an error **"NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined"**, meaning the numpy that was imported in *basic.py* is not passed to the *Main.py*.

I guess that a similar error would occur for the code in *load_data.py* since 'pandas' would not be a defined name.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Naturally, I am importing the python files without the .py extension.

Comment: Each module has its own namespace.  Importing in one module does not make it available in others.  You have to import in every file that uses `numpy`.  The idea is one of *encapsulation*.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)

Comment: @BobSmith then don't put `.py` in your code and confuse people.

Comment: Any ideas about what? That's how Python works; names must be defined in the scope they're used.

Comment: Import numpy in all modules that use it. After the first import, Python knows that the module has already been loaded and just adds a reference in the module namespace.

Comment: Just `import` the modules into any file that references them. Python caches imported modules in `sys.modules`, so any subsequent `import`s after the first are not actually reloaded. The only implied imports are those defined by the language or the `_bultin__` module.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `numpy` module imported in `basic.py` has a reference defined only withing `basic.py` scope. You have to explictly import `numpy` everywhere you use it.

```
import basic.py
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(7)
import load_data.py
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just thought there could be a way to import the modules once with a global scope.