# Import a module with imports inside: NameError with nested import statement

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

I cannot figure this out.

**Intent:**
Have cleaner .ipynb files by putting repeatedly used functions in a module that can be imported.

**Action taken:**
Created file fileload.py in same folder as .ipynb. This includes imports itself that workflawlessly in the .ipynb.

**Problem:**
Error Message:

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

**Code:**
fileload.py:

```
import pandas as pd
# load a single file as a numpy array
def load_file(filepath):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    return dataframe.values
```

main.py:

```
import fileload
fileload.load_file('<path>')
```

**Attempted Fix:**
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335948/nameerror-imported-modules-when-script-is-broken-down-in-multiple-python-file) importing pandas in the main should work - but it doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407090/nameerror-name-pd-is-not-defined/45859043 Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Is that the exact contents of `main.py`?

Comment: @AnoopRDesai there is a lot more. Even if I import it inside the same notebook and recompute all the cells from scratch the error persists.
TinNguyen hinted that this might be a jupyter inconsistency. I cannot work on verifying that right now. I was hoping for a conceptual misunderstanding n my part.

Comment: So you would ideally get that error the first time you reference `pd`. When you import it into the same notebook, do you by any chance reference `pd` before the import?

Comment: Not in cell based execution.

Comment: The most reasonable explanation is that the Python interpreter you are running does not have `pandas` installed. How do you execute this code? Can you confirm which Python interpreter is executed (`which` for mac/linux, `where` win)? Last test would be `python -c 'import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__);`

Comment: Picture this: you have an ipynb that works flawlessly that also uses pandas as pd. Then you remove 3 functions and put them in a separate file that you import. And the. You get the error. You try to troubleshoot by adding pandas in the new file that you imported, but to no avail.